# How to disable bootstrap popover on tap in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am getting one major issue of bootstrap popover, it's working fine in desktop but not in mobile, When I tap on button which has pophover it's opening tooltip at first tap and firing event on second tap.

> **In sort :** bootstrap popover not firing event in one tap in mobile device, It's showing tool-tip instead.

I want to get it disabled on mobile devices, or fire event with tooltip.

Let me show codes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
  <a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Some content" class="">Hover over me</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').click(function(){
        alert("I am clicked");
})
```

What I tried

```
var win = $(window).width();
   if(win<767) {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').removeAttr('data-toggle');
      // Or something like this disable popover
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popoverDisabled();
    }
```

So, Is there any function or attributes which can fix this, any help/suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: Instead of trying to disable the popover on mobile, you should wrap the popover code in an `if` statement, like this `if (!mobile) { ...code }`

Answer (score 3):

This will work: `$('.className').popover('disable');`

Any for mobile only, for example:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        $('.className').popover('disable');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Check Mobile Version run this function :-

```
detectmob();
function detectmob() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover("hide");
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: No this is not working, May i know what `popover("hide")` does

Comment: For Your reference check this https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_popover_methods&stacked=h

Comment: I tried `$("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('destroy');` but not works